# Prisma Client Extension - Computed Fields with ExpressJS - Issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I am having an issue where I am using Prisma version 5.3.1 along with ExpressJS where I am trying to generate a computed field for `full_name` on my `Author` model.

Here is my Prisma schema:

```
generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "sqlite"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Author {
    id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
    first_name String
    last_name  String
    created_at DateTime @default(now())
    updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
    Book       Book[]
}

model Book {
    id             Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
    title          String
    is_fiction     Boolean
    date_published DateTime
    created_at     DateTime @default(now())
    updated_at     DateTime @updatedAt
    author         Author   @relation(fields: [author_id], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    author_id      Int
}
```

This is my db server setup:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

let db: PrismaClient;

declare global {
    var __db: PrismaClient | undefined;
}

if (!global.__db) {
    global.__db = new PrismaClient();
}

db = global.__db;

export {
    db
};
```

This is my Author type:

```
export type Author = {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    full_name?: string;
};
```

This is my ExpressJS service:

```
import { db } from "../../../utils/db.server";

import { Author } from "../../../types/Author";


/**
 * @description Calls the Database to retrieve an array of all Authors.
 * @returns An array of Authors.
 */
const getAll = async () : Promise<Author[]> => {
    try {
        db.$extends({
            result: {
                author: {
                    full_name: {
                        needs: { first_name: true, last_name: true },
                        compute(author) {
                            return `${author.first_name} ${author.last_name}`
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        });

        return await db.author.findMany({
            select: {
                id: true,
                first_name: true,
                last_name: true,
                full_name: true
            }
        });
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(error);

        throw error;
    }
};


export {getAll};
```

For some reason, when I am returning the results, it does not show the `full_name` field. I've looked at the documentation and believe I am implementing it correctly, however advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: does it only omits first_name or some other fields too?

Comment: @VladVladov It only shows the `id`, `first_name` and `last_name` fields when I run the route for `getAll`. I want it to also show the `full_name` computed field.

Comment: well you can call regular js func instead of $extends - store findMany result and do map func that adds full_name to each row